# Unexpected token ':' when getting Json data

Tags: json

[This link](https://getquote.herokuapp.com/get) gets some random JSON data. To the best of my knowledge, it is valid.

However, when I try to get it using this code:

```
$.ajax({
               type: "GET",
               url: "https://getquote.herokuapp.com/get",
               dataType: "jsonp",
               success: function(data){
                  console.log("getting data...")
                  console.log(data);
               },
               error: function(err){
                  console.log("ran into an error...");
               }
            });
```

... I get an error that says, "Unexpected token :"

Comment: Why are you using `jsonp` to retrieve data? As I see that endpoint returns plain json.

Comment: @stm - I get the "XMLHttpRequest cannot load" error. Isn't it good practice to use jsonp anyway?

Comment: First of all take a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2067472/what-is-jsonp-all-about

Comment: Jsonp approach should be used only with API implemented in appropriate way (and this quote endpoint isn't such one). So I your case you need to change `dataType` parameter to correct one. I believe `dataType: 'json' ` should work out

Comment: @stm - I tried it, but it didn't work.

Comment: ok, try to remove `dataType` completely from parameters, thus jQuery will use parser depending on MIME type of response data.
If it won't work, plz provide jsfiddle with your code sample.